# PAssing an entity Object to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

So i have an object that i want to pass to another jframe.

```
 Employee emp = user.getEmpid();
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            new SheduleApp().setVisible(true);
                        }
```

wat i want to do is to pass the emp object to

```
SheduleApp(emp).setVisible(true);
```

but apparently you cant pass an Object to a Jframe....
Please help with an alternative or sggestion

Answer (score 1):

In the code of SheduleApp JFrame, just put the field and constructor

```
private Employee emp;
public SheduleApp (Employee getObj)
{
     this.emp = getObj;
}
```

So, you can use emp field object in JFrame SheduleApp.

Answer (score 0):

if your emp object is inside method i.e. locally created then mark it final and create constructor in SheduleApp for accepting emp object.

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor in your class `SheduleApp` and use it

```
public class SheduleApp extends JFrame{
   private Employee emp;
   public SheduleApp (Employee emp)
   {
     this.emp = emp;
   }

   // rest of your codes
 }
```

or you can have separate Get and Set methods.

```
public class SheduleApp extends JFrame {

private Employee employee;

public SheduleApp() {
}

public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
    this.employee = employee;
}

public Employee getEmployee() {
    return employee;
}
}
```